# How to properly describe/ cast typescript polymorphic self in abstract class or interface

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class in this case, but the same applies to interfaces when `this` is used. Admittedly I may be using it incorrectly and so here I am.

```
abstract class Foo{
    abstract clone({arg}: {arg: string}): this
}

interface Bar {
    clone({arg}: {arg: string}): this
}
```

Either of these describe the setup. Now I get what that's saying: "I will return literally this thing I am not a new instance of that thing" hence the compiler error when doing:

```
class MyFoo extends Foo{
    clone({arg}: {arg: string}): this {
        return new MyFoo(arg); // compiler error a new MyFoo is not `this`
    }
}
```

So what I am after is really a way to say:

```
clone({arg}: {arg: string}): typeof this
```

Now the above doesn't compile, so what I have resorted too is:

```
class MyFoo extends Foo{
    clone({arg}: {arg: string}): this {
        return <this>new MyFoo(arg); // no compiler error but this feels wrong?
        // OR
        return new MyFoo(arg) as this; // no compiler error but this feels wrong?
    }
}
```

So thats where I am at. Is this how we should be handling this type of thing?

Comment: I'd favour `return new MyFoo() as this;`...nothing wrong with doing it that way.

Comment: You could also return a generic interface/class like `abstract class Foo<T>{ abstract clone(): T }` and use it like `class MyFoo extends Foo<MyFoo>`

Comment: Maybe also consider moving clone functionality into an interface: `interface Cloneable<T> { clone(): T }` then `class MyFoo implements Cloneable<MyFoo> { ... }`

Comment: The generic is a nice idea, didn't immediately cross my mind, also the use of the interface to spread that around beyond a class implementation is a nice amendment!

Comment: Hmmm. this works well until you do something like a driver pattern, then the host for the driver has to be Generic as well. But I will fiddle with it some more or I will carry on. the `as this` or `<this>result` both get past the compiler errors